# If column data is null or contains an empty string then 'N/A'

Tags: sql

I have a column called County, and in this column sometimes there is a county and other times its either empty or contains NULL. So far I am able to change it when there is an empty string to N/A, but not sure how to change it if there is a NULL as well.
So far I am using a case statement to check if the column contains an empty string

```
case County when '' then 'N/A' end
```

but I need to check if the column data is NULL as well and change it to N/A.

So in short, if any data in the County column is an empty string or is NULL then I need to add N/A.

Comment: depend on your RDBMS, e.g. Oracle doesn't support empty strings, so you can put just `nvl(County, 'N/A')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case when County = '' or County is null
     then 'N/A' 
     else County 
end
```

Comment: This is working, but its not catching all the NULL's, I still have a couple stragglers, any idea why?
Oh BTW, its County and not Country :)

Comment: I am sure it is catching all NULLs. Please add example data to see those strange data.

Comment: My mistake it was a typo from my end

Answer (score 3):

One way would be

```
Case when County <>  '' then  County ELSE 'N/A' end
```

Both nulls and empty strings end up at the else.

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(County)),''), 'N/A') County`